# Use map with struct key cause crash

Tags: c++

I create a simple map use struct as key but crash when running.
Could you point out the issue? Big thanks.

The code is crash when putting item 3rd.

```
...
typedef struct pmjob
{
    std::string jobId;
    std::string jobGroup;
    int reportingPeriod;
    int compressionType;
    bool operator == (const struct pmjob &other) const
    {
        return ((jobGroup.compare(other.jobGroup) == 0) && (reportingPeriod == other.reportingPeriod));
    }

    bool operator < (const struct pmjob &other) const
    {
        if (reportingPeriod < other.reportingPeriod)
        {
            if(jobGroup.compare(other.jobGroup) == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
        //return ((reportingPeriod < other.reportingPeriod) || (jobGroup.compare(other.jobGroup)));
    }
}PMJob;

typedef std::map<PMJob, int> PMJobMap;
PMJobMap List;
typedef std::pair<PMJob, int> PMJobPair;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator is invalid.

`bool operator < (const struct pmjob &other) const`

It doesn't provide strict weak ordering.

Example of valid comparator:

```
bool operator < (const struct pmjob &other) const
{
    // first compare most important member
    if (reportingPeriod < other.reportingPeriod) {
        return false;
    }
    if (other.reportingPeriod < reportingPeriod) {
        return true;
    }

    // less important member
    if (compressionType < other.compressionType) {
        return false;
    }
    if (other.compressionType < compressionType) {
        return true;
    }

    if (jobId < other.jobId) {
        return false;
    }
    if (other.jobId < jobId) {
        return true;
    }

    if (jobGroup < other.jobGroup) {
        return false;
    }
    if (other.jobGroup < jobGroup) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

or using `std::tie`:

```
bool operator < (const struct pmjob &other) const
{
    return std::tie(jobId, jobGroup, reportingPeriod, compressionType) < 
        std::tie(other.jobId, other.jobGroup, other.reportingPeriod, other.compressionType);
}
```

Comment: Could you suggest one way?

Comment: Thanks @ikleschenkov. You mean we must use compare all string in struct ? I will check it. But how about if I just only use reportingPeriod and jobGroup as key. I mean I don't care jobId and compressionType.

Comment: @doccocobai then compare only `jobId` and `compressionType` (use only them in expression).